# How to convert HexString to Int signed or unsigned without prefixed mask length? [Python]

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

**Question:**

How to convert HexString to Int signed or unsigned without prefixed mask length in Python?

Yeah... already exists topics about this. But the answers were insuficient or incomplete for this specification.
I just wanted to pass a string - nothing more - and get its equivalent (signed or unsigned, any size).

**Examples:**

```
Passing FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Getting -1

Passing 9F1281F0
Getting -1626177040

Passing 1234
Getting 4660
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question but a code sample.

Comment: Well, there is questions about it... but I can't response yet. I found myself in need of this, and think it can help more people.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Self answered questions are perfectly fine, but you should present them as a true question and then an answer. You question could explain that you want a way to convert hex strings to signed integers without a definite size or mask, and actually say that the other answers you have found do not address this requirement. Then you can immediately answer (there is a button for that...). But as currently written, this post does not follow SO rules (read [ask]).

Comment: Thanks Serge. This was more friendly and helpfull than the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours searching for this question, I found a solution.

It accounts every hex digit as a 4 bit integer, although this is not always true, it wont be a problem too.

Ex: 0x7 is 0b111. And so, the integer in Python will have 3 bits. Check with:

```
a = 7
print( a.bit_length() )
#3
```

But if there is no fourth bit from the most significant digit (signal bit), it will be calculated as 0, exactly what we want in this case.

So, the code (not optimized) but the most legible I can present is this:

```
HEX_BITS = 4

def shift_left1( bits ):
    #Left shift adding 1 instead of 0
    mask = 0
    for i in range( bits ):
        mask = (mask << 1) + 1
    return mask

def hex_signal( value, bits ):
    # Retuns the mask with bit signal
    signal_mask =  1 << bits
    return -( value & ( signal_mask ) )

def hex_without_signal( value, bits ):
    # Returns value with the number of bits given (from less significant to most)
    return value & shift_left1( bits )

def hex2dec( hstring, signed=True ):
    value = int( hstring, 16)
    if signed: #Do we want to check the signal?
        value_bits = len( hstring ) * HEX_BITS # A full hex digit have four bits
        shift_times = value_bits - 1 # Times to subfunctions shifts
        signal_mask = hex_signal( value, shift_times ) # Mask with bit value setted
        unsigned_hex_mask = hex_without_signal( value, shift_times ) # Value without most significant bit
        return signal_mask | unsigned_hex_mask # Or bit a bit from the unsigned value and signal mask
    else: # If not just returns the native conversion
        return value
```

**Examples:**

```
print( hex2dec( "2" ) )
#2
print( hex2dec( "E" ) )
#-2
print( hex2dec( "4" ) )
#4
print( hex2dec( "FF" ) )
#-1
print( hex2dec( "0F" ) )
#15
print( hex2dec( "1F" ) )
#31
print( hex2dec( "1234" ) )
#4660
print( hex2dec( "9F1281F0" ) )
#-1626177040
```